How can I get refunded from the issue "Associated Token Account Program: create (Program Error: "Provided owner is not allowed")"
I'm new to this platform, could anyone help me with this issue? Thank you!

Please add more information to your question. What code are you calling? What are you trying to do. What do you want to get refunded for? Its not possible to answer this question like this.
